# AngularJS Library only works after I refresh the page, if I change states it stops working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a library [video.js](http://videojs.com/). I used the example code from the website:

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls 
preload="auto" width="1000" height="600" data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [1, 
1.5, 2] }'>
         <source src="file\undefined\1501667652598.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and added the scripts/css:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.4/video.js"></script>
```

When I straight refresh the page, it works fine. But if I change states, it defaults to the regular video player. What could be the problem I'm facing?

States definition looks like that:

```
angular.module("pamm").config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("user.topic", {
            url: "/topic",
            views: {
                "content@user": {
                    templateUrl: "feature/user/topic/topic-list.html"
                }
            },
            params: {
                section: null,
                type: null
            }
        })
        .state("user.topic.details", {
            url: "/details/:id",
            views: {
                "content@user": {
                    templateUrl: "feature/user/topic/topic-details.html"
                }
            },
            params: {course: null}
        })
        .state("user.topic.result", {
            url: "/result",
            views: {
                "content@user": {
                    templateUrl: "feature/user/topic/topic-result.html"
                }
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in plunkr?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I'm working on a large application and it will require reproducing a large piece of angular code to do it... I just hope someone had a similar problem.

Comment: Can you just post here the relevant part of your router ?

Comment: Defaults to regular video  means?

Comment: @slacker I think the library makes the video player custom, if he changes states, it doesn't apply anymore and it goes back to html5 default video player (you'll see it if you try to put a video on your browser or just put a streaming link in a new tab, sometimes it works and is read by default html5 reader)

Comment: @slacker just changes to a default html5 video player.

Comment: @Alburkerk added some code for state definition

Comment: I'm using Vimeo player in my application and it works fine on state changes too.  So was confused withthe term default player

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup your player manually by calling its [function](http://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html#manual-setup) if the `<video>` tag is only added after the page load complete.

The reason is `video.js` will scan your HTML and setup any existing `<video>` tags automatically, but unfortunately it cannot watch changes in your HTML when angular updates it. ([reference](http://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html#automatic-setup))

You can add the manual setup code inside a route controller.

Comment: Thank you! But what do you do if you have a few videos on the same page?

Comment: I think normal selectors should work. Not sure if you can setup multiple at the same time using class selector, if cannot then use different id or class name.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your code inside this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
        (function ($) {

       //your code

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why should we do it ?